# How do I give access provided user has at least one type of access granted?

Tags: users, routes

I use Drupal 7. My module implements two types of access permissions, named:

- `access MYMODULE foo`
- `access MYMODULE bar`

I want to grant a user access to a particular path (`node/%node/MYMODULE`) provided the user holds at least one of these access permissions.

The snippet below is how this is currently implemented, and it obviously only grants access based upon the first of these (`access MYMODULE foo`).

How do I add, and test for, the second permission (`access MYMODULE bar`)?

```
/**
 * Callback function to see if a node is acceptable for poll menu items.
 */
function _MYMODULE_menu_access($node, $perm) {
  return user_access($perm);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['node/%node/MYMODULE'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_page', 1),
    'access callback' => '_MYMODULE_menu_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'access MYMODULE foo'),
    'file' => 'MYMODULE.nodes.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
  return $items;
}
```